# Wordpress Menus apearing in one browser, but not on another

Tags: wordpress, menu

good morning.

I am building a wordpress website, that the theme has these cools features menus for visitors and logged in users.

I have two accounts logged in my google chrome browser, so two pages open with my website. But when I am browsing my pages with one account the menu appears, but on another brower, it doesn't.

The theme allows the users to be logged in, but in this scenario I am explaining, I am just browsing the pages as a visitor using different browsers. The cache has been cleaned several times, inside wordpress and also the browser cache.

I don't know what else could it be.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you,

Tiago

[This one you can see the menu on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDIcG.jpg)

[But on this image you see that the menu is gone, I can still have access to the menu, in some other way, but I would rather have it like the image before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUlgu.jpg)

Comment: Could be a cache issue, flush the cache then test.

Comment: That was the first thing I have done. The images I've shared on this post are from different browsers that I use here all within chrome, just logged in different accounts. But the cache is cleared.